# Limiting joined table to one result Mssql

Tags: php, sql-server

I have two tables, one that stores general information and one that holds comments.

The structure is that a record in **table one** can have many corresponding results in **table two**.
However I am trying to write a query that pulls everything from **table one** and only the last comment from **table 2**.

For example, say there is a user in **table one** and they have 5 comments in **table two**, the query I want would pull the person from **table one** and only the last comment out of **table two**.

I have this query below however this will pull everything from **table one** which is what I want, but if there are multiple records for the record in **table one** it will bring them all in.

Quick example

```
Query results
ID  Field two  Field three  Field four     field out of table 2
1      Data       Data          Data           Comment 1
2      Data       Data          Data           Comment 1
2      Data       Data          Data           Comment 2
3      Data       Data          Data           Comment 1
4      Data       Data          Data           Comment 1
5      Data       Data          Data           Comment 1
```

As you can see as there are two comments for the record with ID 2 it is pulled in twice and what I want is just the last comment to be shown:

```
SELECT Qualitycontrol.ID, Qualitycontrol.MachineNo, Qualitycontrol.Description,    
    Qualitycontrol.CreatedTime, Qualitycontrol.ProductCode, Qualitycontrol.WorkOrder, 
    Qualitycontrol.Quantity, QualityControl_Comments.Comment
FROM Qualitycontrol 
LEFT OUTER JOIN QualityControl_Comments
           ON Qualitycontrol.ID = QualityControl_Comments.QCUID
WHERE (Qualitycontrol.CreatedTime 
        BETWEEN CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)))
ORDER BY Qualitycontrol.MachineNo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform an `OUTER APPLY` instead of a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT Qualitycontrol.ID, Qualitycontrol.MachineNo, Qualitycontrol.Description,  
       Qualitycontrol.CreatedTime, Qualitycontrol.ProductCode, Qualitycontrol.WorkOrder, 
       Qualitycontrol.Quantity, Qc.Comment
FROM Qualitycontrol 
OUTER APPLY (
   SELECT TOP 5 Comment
   FROM QualityControl_Comments
   WHERE Qualitycontrol.ID = QCUID
   ORDER BY ... DESC -- whatever defines order in QualityControl_Comments
) AS Qc(Comment)                  
WHERE (Qualitycontrol.CreatedTime BETWEEN CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)))
ORDER BY Qualitycontrol.MachineNo
```

Answer (score 1):

You can perform the `JOIN` and take the last comment per record based on `MAX(CommentId)`. Something like this added to your `WHERE` clause should work:

```
AND qcc.ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM QualityControl_Comments WHERE QCID = qc.ID)
```

**Full query (with aliases):**

```
SELECT  qc.ID ,
        qc.MachineNo ,
        qc.Description ,
        qc.CreatedTime ,
        qc.ProductCode ,
        qc.WorkOrder ,
        qc.Quantity ,
        qcc.Comment
FROM    Qualitycontrol qc
LEFT JOIN QualityControl_Comments qcc ON qc.ID = qcc.QCUID
WHERE   ( qc.CreatedTime BETWEEN CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
                                     AND     DATEADD(DAY, 1,
                                                     CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) )
        AND qcc.ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM QualityControl_Comments WHERE QCID = qc.ID)
ORDER BY qc.MachineNo
```